# How do I specify my background-image in markup instead

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, background-image

I have some code that I did not write that currently has a **background-image**.  I want to keep the exact look but instead of setting the image in CSS, I want to set it in my markup but I don't know how.

This is how the image is currently set in CSS

```
.clean-topbar{
    background-image:url(http://www.elpasodeventa.com/mls_content/gep/photos/818802/20191118214112529586000000-o.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    position: relative;
    height:200px;
}
```

Here is the part of the markup where the image is displayed:

```
<div class="clean-topbar">
...
```

Please help me specify the image in my HTML markup instead of the CSS.  Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/carolinebeltran/vmgq1ena/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding phoenixstudio's answer, what you can do is specify the inline background-image style like this

```html
<div class="clean-topbar" style="background-image:url()">

</div>
```

And then in your CSS control the way the background is displayed:

```css
.clean-topbar {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: cover; // or contain whichever serves you
}
```

A good option for you would be to use [Vanilla Lazyload](https://www.andreaverlicchi.eu/lazyload/) to reduce loading times and improve page speed.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much for helping out.  There were other good solutions but this was the easiest and cleanest.

Answer (score 4):

you can use inline css `<div style="background-image:url(http://www.elpaso...);">`

Comment: I did like your solution and voted as useful answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to avoid using a background-image and seperate CSS, but instead use an `img` tag and inline styles in HTML only, that would be

```
<div><img src="http://www.elpasodeventa.com/mls_content/gep/photos/818802/20191118214112529586000000-o.jpg" style="height:200px;object-fit:cover;"></div>
```

If however, you simply want to move the external CSS to inline styles, that would be

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://www.elpasodeventa.com/mls_content/gep/photos/818802/20191118214112529586000000-o.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;        background-position:center;background-size:cover;position: relative;height:200px;">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<img>` tag. [check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `<img />` tag, and add a css class which provides width/height from the other code. After that you can use the `src=""` property to insert the link of the picture.